# CSS dynamically determine number of columns based on max-content of children

Tags: css, multiple-columns, max-content

I'm trying to use [css `columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) to display a dynamic number of columns based on the maximum width needed for the children to display nicely (such that the text doesn't wrap onto a new line where possible). I'd then like to stretch each element to fit the available space in the column.

This is what I have (Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvfejp8m/)):

[image]

But this is what I'd like to see (all elements have equal width):

[image]

This is the code I've tried:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div>
    Lorem
  </div>
  <div>
     Ipsum
  </div>
  <div>
    Dollar
  </div>
  <div>
    Euro
  </div>
  <div>
    Bitcoin
  </div> 
</div>
```

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.columns {
  columns: auto;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  background: #4cafff;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.columns > div {
  width: max-content;
  background: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`max-content` is not work like that. It is make the content not to wrap. I mean, width or height of content will be maximum size of your content. It will be fit.

If you want to equal width of all element, you can use specific pixel for width.

Like this:

```
.columns > div {
  width: 95px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: No, I want the width to be `max-content` so that it uses as many columns as it can such that the text does not wrap onto a new line.

Answer (score -1):

Try this CSS

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #4cafff;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.columns > div {
  background: #4caf50;
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```